# Why can't my application detect the QR code through intergrated webcam?

Tags: c#, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am trying to get my application to read a QR code and display the embedded information as a string. So far, I have failed and I can't get it to work. Any help?

```
public partial class frmBookSystem : Form
{

    public frmBookSystem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private FilterInfoCollection CaptureDevices;
    private VideoCaptureDevice videoSource;

    private void cmdDetectQR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(CaptureDevices[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(VideoSource_NewFrame);
        videoSource.Start();
    }
    private void VideoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        picQRframe.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    }
    private void frmBookSystem_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        foreach (FilterInfo Device in CaptureDevices)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(Device.Name);
        }
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice();
    }

    private void cmdDetect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BarcodeReader Reader = new BarcodeReader();
        Result result = Reader.Decode((Bitmap)picQRframe.Image);
        try
        {
            lblcaption.Text = result.ToString().Trim();
        }
        catch
        {
            lblcaption.Text = "nothing";
        }
    }
```

There are no errors on my application so far. I just really need help with this. Thanks!

Comment: Please refer to the materials starting from this page and related pages. [Camera barcode scanner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-camerabarcode)

Comment: You state that your application has no errors. How can we help you?

Comment: Some web-cams do not support auto-focus, which is needed by most decoders to get crisp enough images of the barcode.  Assuming you are using a web-cam with Windows 10, you can try a free store app like [JustScanIt](http://aka.ms/JustScanIt) to see if the camera capabilities have reasonable features.